# How to edit APEX code after deployment?

Tags: apex, deployment

How can I change/add to my APEX code after deploying the code to my organization?

Comment: Why would you want to modify production code while it is on your production org ? Every mistake could have a huge impact.

Comment: Totally agree.  This is just against best practice.  It isnt allowed, nor should you want it to be allowed.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You still need to manage that code in a sandbox org.  So any changes you make to the code after it is deployed to production, you need to make in the sandbox, and then deploy them to production which overwrites the previous version.

This really is just the SF platform forcing us to use development best practice.  You never want to write changes directly into a production environment.  This really forces us to create a development lifecycle which includes proper testing and due diligence.

As @Sdry points out in a comment, a mistake could have HUGE impacts in your production environment.

Comment: Can i use the same change set to deploy the code? or do i have to create a different change set each time?

Comment: I do most of my deployment through the IDE but I believe you should use a new change set each time.  I'm not totally certain if an already existing change set will reflect the changes made int eh sandbox or not if you try to redeploy it after changing it's components.  Perhaps someone can jump in with this, as I am not totally certain.

Comment: Looks like you can't reuse it.  See the third bullet...http://login.salesforce.com/help/doc/en/changesets_best_practices.htm

Comment: But, you can clone the original change set, re-upload, and be on your way. I personally use the Force.com IDE for code tweaks myself, but that is because I'm the only developer in my organization that works on our production code.

Comment: Correct.  I also do this, but I think we can both agree it should be done very carefully and at your own risk, and not exactly the best practice

Answer (score 2):

You can edit it directly in the org (Setup->Develop->Apex classes or equivalent) or in the Development Console (Setup->Development Console, then File->Open) or in Eclipse Force.com IDE and simply deploy it again.

EDIT: This does not apply to all cases, as noted in the comment below. The original post didn't specify deployment to production.

Comment: I think this is a bit misleading.  This is making it seem as though you can change the Apex in the Production org.  you should specify that this needs to be done in the sandbox, and then redeployed.

Comment: @Dunc44 True, of course. I edited the post.